# How to Add Attributes to .cs file generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a ASP.net MVC web app and trying to add validation attributes  to a ClientsTbl.cs file I have generated from a SQL server using entity framework. I have done scaffolding and created the view and the controller for the Table(Model), but for some reason the scaffold did not recognize the primary key column as a primary key. On top of that it will not let me add attributes in []. I can't even change the field description that appears above the views form text box.  How do I do the above in the following class?

```
namespace Testit.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class ClientsTbl
{
    public ClientsTbl()
    {
        this.ProgramClientTbls = new HashSet<ProgramClientTbl>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CenterId { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName1 { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName2 { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual CenterTbl CenterTbl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProgramClientTbl> ProgramClientTbls { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Comment: Why will it not let you?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a metadata class to do that. For example, if Id, FirstName, and LastName are required fields, you can create a new class like below.

```
public class ClientsTblMetadata
{
    [Required()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to add a new partial class with a `MetadataType` attribute. Please make sure that this class is located under the same namespace, otherwise it won't work.

```
namespace Testit.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ClientsTblMetadata))] // you need this line of code.
    public partial class ClientsTbl
```